# How to use data annotation with SQL views? MVC & EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

My database contains both tables and views. I can use "Data annotation" with tables :), but I failed with Views:(.
I use meta data classes to apply data annotation on the EF generated classes.

```
class V_TasksList_MD
{

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> SubmitDate { get; set; }


    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }


    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime DueDate { get; set; }


    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ProgressDate { get; set; }


    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CompleteDate { get; set; }


    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ApproveDate { get; set; }


}

[MetadataType(typeof(V_TasksList_MD))]
public partial class V_TasksList
{

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Getting an error, value not displayed correctly?

Comment: No errors. just date format does not work as my annotation @Steve Greene

Comment: Try adding the DataType: `[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat( DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true )]`. Another option is to just format within the view: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ResgistrationhaseDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")`

Comment: @Steve Greene Using DataType(DataType.Date) will make chrome add datepicker to the field automaticaly, whick is bad for me :(,I use your second option for now untile i discover what is the problem